# REST API for Google Cloud Fusion

Tags: rest, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am exploring new tools for data pipelines. Trying Google's Data Fusion I was very surprised to not see any REST connector.

It seems like REST API's are a very standard way to access data and I am confused not to see it available.

Am I missing something ? Are there REST source/sink connectors ? And if not, why ? Is that a design decision by CDAP ?

Comment: Hi nate. Would you mind to be a bit more specific regarding these REST connectors? What is that you are trying to achieve/which methods do you actually want? Just in case, [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/rest/) you have the REST API reference for creating and managing your Cloud Data Fusion instances on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

For the any tasks related to the managing Cloud Data Fusion instances you might consider looking at particular [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations) reference as *@Sergi Muñoz* has already mentioned in the comment above, leveraging `projects.locations` method which is perfectly explained by *@Guillem Xercavinsin* from the practice perspective in the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942876/access-cdap-rest-api-of-a-cloud-data-fusion-instance).

However, when it turns for Data Fusion source connectors, it is worthy to mentioned about *[HTTP plugin](https://github.com/data-integrations/http)* which is available to install from Data Fusion Hub [inventory](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/concepts/overview#plugin). This plugin gives you a collection of variety features for [*Batch*](https://github.com/data-integrations/http/blob/develop/docs/HTTP-batchsource.md) and [*Streaming*](https://github.com/data-integrations/http/blob/develop/docs/HTTP-streamingsource.md) purposes matching particular use case.

You can read more [here](https://medium.com/cdapio/processing-http-data-with-cdap-6793fa9bbd73) where [@Edwin Elia](https://medium.com/@edwinelia?source=post_page-----6793fa9bbd73----------------------) explains processing HTTP data within HTTP plugin.