# How can I connect to Datafusion instance using CDAP CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I had installed CDAP on my linux machine and I am trying to connect to GCP datafusion instance from CLI in the format of ./cdap cli --uri https://xxxxxxxx.datafusion.googleusercontent.com/cdap/ns/default and I am facing connection timed out issue. How to resolve this

Comment: Seems to be URI format is wrong, look at the source CLI [documentation](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/6.1.1/en/reference-manual/cli-api.html#options).

Comment: @code-tutorial: What is it that you are trying to do? You can't connect CDAP cli to an instance. Can you follow the guidelines in this https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference doc. You can use gcloud cli to get an access token (gcloud auth print-access-token) and use it for the REST apis. Accessing CDAP APIs via REST can be found here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942876/access-cdap-rest-api-of-a-cloud-data-fusion-instance)